# What is the difference between value types and primitive types?

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, primitive-types

Reading a book about C# I noticed that sometimes is mentioned value type and sometimes primitive type for some data type (e.g. int, double). I thought they were the same thing, but they are really the same or not?

What is the difference between a value type and a primitive type? 
Are they the same thing?

**EDIT**

The question is not only related to C# programming Language, I was wondering how them are different even in any other language.

Comment: A struct, for ex., is a value type but not a primitive.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types

Comment: The formal classification of the types are: Value types and Reference types. Primitive or native types, is a way to refers those basic types such as int, char, bool, etc... they normally are Value types.

Comment: @DJKRAZE see the edit, the question isn't strictly related to C# and .NET ...

Comment: The problem here is the answer to the question is subtly different in different languages so any correct answer has to be either very long or so general as to be of little use.

Comment: `The question is not only related to C# programming Language` So you assume every language treats them the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A value type is *usually* whatever type reside on the Stack .

A primitive type is a type defined at the programming language level, often it is even a value type, directly supported by the compiler of the language.

However this is a summary general answer because each programming language have different set of differences between the two types ...

Comment: -1 - except Eric Lippert calls this point about the stack a 'myth' and he should probably know : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: Yes, better to speak in terms of semantics, not storage (though how they are stored is relevant too in some instances)

Comment: @JamesGaunt yes, that could be true for C#, but for Java or ANSI C ? Are you sure that my answer is wrong ?

Comment: @aleroot - fair point,  I see the question is tagged with multiple languages, but the first line refers to C#. I will rescind my -1.

Comment: -1 for "A value type is usually whatever type reside on the Stack".

Comment: I still don't understand :(

Comment: Whether value types are allocated on the stack or somewhere else is an implementation detail, regardless of the language. Eric Lippert's article can be applied to Java just as well. Also this answer does not really explain the difference, and stating that value types are not directly supported by the compiler can be very misleading.

Answer (score -2):

No they are not. A value type is copied and while a reference type is being referenced. See the image[image: Value vs Reference]

**Edit**
My mistake. Here's an tutorial for the differences: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11212/Primitive-Reference-and-Value-Types

Comment: The question was about the difference between value types and primitive types, not value types and reference types.

Comment: The difference to explain is not between value type and reference type , reread the question ...

Comment: He was asking about value vs. Primative **not** value vs. Reference

Comment: -1, read the question...