# How do I call a function of an existing object from outside its class?

Tags: java

I'm modifying some existing Java code for an assignment and I can't figure out how to call a function of an existing object from within an ActionListener.

**There will only ever be one instance of "myGame".**

Here is the relevant code;

```
public class myGame extends JFrame { 
    public myGame() { 
        //...snip...

        statsBar = new JLabel(""); 
        add(statsBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

        add(new Board(statsBar)); 

        setResizable(false); 
        setVisible(true);

        addMenubar();
    } 

    private void addMenubar() {
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu topMnuGame = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem mnuSolve = new JMenuItem("Solve");
        mnuSolve.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

              // freshGame.solveGame();
              // this is where I need to call the solveGame function
              // for the "freshGame" instance.
              solveGame();

            }
        });
        topMnuGame.add(mnuSolve);
        menubar.add(topMnuGame);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

      myGame freshGame = new myGame();

    }

}
```

.

```
public class Board extends JPanel { 

public Board(JLabel statsBar) {
    this.statsBar = statsBar; 

    //..snip..

    addMouseListener( new gameAdapter() ); 
}

    public void solveGame() {
    // .. do stuff with object ..
    }

}
```

**So my question is, how can I call "solveGame()" from within the "myGame" class using the "freshGame" instance?**

Comment: Your class names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: If there is only one instance, then calling `solveGame()` can only be called on that instance. Is it not working? What is your actual problem?

Comment: Did you try making freshGame as a global variable of myGame class?

Comment: The error I'm receiving is;
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol: method solveGame()

Comment: @Deeksha Yes I've tried making it a global of the myGame class, as follows;
`public class myGame extends JFrame {
        final public myGame freshGame = new myGame(); 
        public myGame() { //.. }`

Comment: `solveGame()` is in `Board`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand fully whats your problem. What i understood is you are not able to call `solveGame()` function with `freshGame` object which is instance of your `myGame` class.

**1.** Your `solveGame()` function is in `Board` Class so you can only call it by using `Board` instance.
**2** So you have to create instance of `Board` in your  `myGame` class to use it, may be like following.

```
public class myGame extends JFrame { 
  private Board board;
  public myGame() { 
    //...snip...

    statsBar = new JLabel(""); 
    board= Board(statsBar ) // initializing Board Class . you can do your self 

    add(statsBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
    add(new Board(statsBar)); 
    setResizable(false); 
    setVisible(true);
    addMenubar();
} 

private void addMenubar() {
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu topMnuGame = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem mnuSolve = new JMenuItem("Solve");
    mnuSolve.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

          // freshGame.solveGame();
          // this is where I need to call the solveGame function
          // for the "freshGame" instance.
          solveGame();

          // now you can call 
            board.solveGame();
        }
    });
    topMnuGame.add(mnuSolve);
    menubar.add(topMnuGame);
 }
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    myGame freshGame = new myGame();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me get it working as intended. I was forgetting to assign the Board object to the global variable, your answer helped me realize this.

Answer (score 1):

Short generic answer:

In Java, if you have an object, also called an instance of a class, for example

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
```

Then you can access the non-static members of the class for that object like this:

```
myObj.myMethod();
```

Where ever you are going to call a method, you need [a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types) to the right object, so pass it as argument to method that needs it:

```
class OtherClass {
    // snip constructors etc
    public void otherMethod(MyClass obj) {
        obj.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, pass it as constructor parameter and store it in a private member variable, so you call it from methods later.

```
class SomeClass {

    private final MyClass someMyClass;

    SomeClass(MyClass someMyClass) {
        this.someMyClass = someMyClass;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        this.someMyClass.myMethod();
    }
}
```