# What is the difference between char and Character in Java?

Tags: java, char, character

I need to know what is the difference between char and Character in Java because when I was making a java program, the char worked while the Character didn't work.

Comment: a char is a primitive type and a Character is an object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types

Comment: [Wrapper class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) vs [Primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

char is a primitive type that represents a single 16 bit Unicode character while Character is a wrapper class that allows us to use char primitive concept in OOP-kind of way.

Example for char,

```
char ch = 'a';
```

Example of Character,

```
Character.toUpperCase(ch);
```

It converts 'a' to 'A'

Comment: Your second example takes a `char` and returns a `char` not a `Character`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Where does he say it returns `Character`? He's showing an example of how to use the Character class.

Comment: @sansa no idea what I was thinking, you are right, it is a `char`.

Answer (score 10):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html):

> The Character class wraps a value of the primitive type char in an
>   object. An object of type Character contains a single field whose type
>   is char. In addition, this class provides several methods for
>   determining a character's category (lowercase letter, digit, etc.) and
>   for converting characters from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa.
>
> Character information is based on the Unicode Standard, version 6.0.0.

So, char is a primitive type while Character is a class. You can use the Character to wrap char from static methods like `Character.toUpperCase(char c)` to use in a more "OOP way".

I imagine in your program there was an 'OOP' mistake(like init of a Character)   rather than char vs Character mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Character is an Object - thus contains a number of static methods e.g. valueOf(char),toUpperCase()

where char is a primitive data-type

Answer (score 2):

char is a primitive type and Character is a class that acts as a wrapper for char.

The point of the Character class is so you can apply a range of methods to your char if needed.

More information here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html