# ArrayList or Stack of arrays in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, stack

I have a 2D array containing a class for each cell to contain info; ie

```
class gridCell {
    int value;
    Boolean valid;
    int anotherValue;
}

gridCell[][] grid=new gridCell[50][50];
```

This works well and once initialized I can access the array by using

```
grid[10][10].value=42;
```

My problem is I want to create a stack or arraylist to store the grid array state at various times.  When I try and create an arraylist by

```
ArrayList<grid> gridList=new ArrayList<grid>();
```

I get the error that grid is not a class.  Same deal if I try and use it in a stack

```
Stack<grid> gridStack = new Stack<grid>();
```

So how can I declare the grid so it can be added to a stack or arraylist?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your class is named `gridCell` not `grid` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the ArrayList type as the exact type you want to save. Since you want to save the grid array, you just need to pass the array type:

```
ArrayList<gridCell[][]> gridList = new ArrayList<gridCell[][]>();
```

You appear to be a little confused between types and variables. In your declaration

`gridCell[][] grid = new gridCell[50][50];`,

you are are declaring a **variable** `grid` of **type** `gridCell[][]`

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I did intend grid to be a variable (array) containing gridcell items within it.

Comment: That declaration worked fine.  How do I add the current grid array to the list?  Using gridList.add(grid) doesn't seem to make a proper copy of the current grid array.

Comment: That's because arrays are [reference types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types). If you want to store successive increments of the grid array, you need to create a copy yourself before adding it. `System.arraycopy()` should help you out.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, you're using a 2 dimensional array, so [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617016/how-do-i-copy-a-2-dimensional-array-in-java) might be better for you. `System.arraycopy()` is really designed for single-dimension arrays.

Comment: OK, arraycopy got it working.  Thanks for the pointers in the right direction.