# Java operators -> how == operator works

Tags: java

Java operator == is used for reference comparison

then how can == be used for comparing int a =1; and int b = 1;

both values are stored in different locations then how it compares

Comment: It is not just used for comparing references: as described in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21), it is  a numerical equality operator, a boolean equality operator *and* a reference equality operator.

Comment: Not actually a duplicate of the one I just marked (reopened); but you should read http://stackoverflow.com/q/8790809/3788176.

Comment: primitive values don't have a location, they only have a value.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Andy, the JLS states that the operator '==' is indeed used for ***reference type*** comparison but also for ***numeric type*** and ***Boolean type*** comparison.

**int** is a ***numeric type.***

When comparing ***numeric types*** the *values* are compared (not the references).

However if you want to determine if the *references* of two integers are equal rather than the *values* then you can use the **Integer** class. This class simply wraps the primitive ***numeric type*** **int**.

Now consider the following code:

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer A = new Integer(1);
    Integer B = new Integer(1);
    Integer C = A;

    if (A == B) System.out.println("Won't print."); // (1)

    if (A.equals(B)) System.out.println("WILL Print!!!"); // (2)

    if (A == C) System.out.println("WILL Print!!!"); // (3)
}
}
```

1. Because A and B are *objects*, the *reference* of A is compared to the *reference* of B. Even though their **int** values are the same, because they are independent *references* this statement is false.
2. The **equals** method compares the **int** values of each **Integer** *object* and thus is true.
3. **Integer** *object* C references *object* A. Hence this reference comparison will be true.