# CodeHS Battleship Java

Tags: java

I'm currently doing coding online to learn coding and am doing the Battleship problem. In this problem you're given methods and the parameters they accept in code.

I am stuck on a problem where the user inputs a row and column and the code verifies whether a row and column were inputted.

```
// Has the location been initialized
public boolean isLocationSet()
{
    if(row == null  && col == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The error I get says: Incomparable types int and (it cuts off but I'm assuming it means null or boolean)

How would I be able to say, if the expected ints `row` and `column` are empty then return false, otherwise return true?

Comment: What are `row` and `col`?  The error implies that they are `int` values, which can *never* be `null`.  So the comparison is invalid and can never be `true`.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. One approach would be to use an Integer object initialized to null instead of an int which cannot be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` cannot be `null`. Nor can a lot of other primitive types. Adjust your conditional accordingly:

```
private int row = 0;
private int col = 0;

// Has the location been initialized
public boolean isLocationSet()
{
    if(row <= 0 || col <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I would also use an OR operator instead of an AND. Presumably your `row` and `col` variables are initialized as `0`. So, for instance, if `row=1` but `col=0` then this `isLocationSet()` method will return false, which would be expected since one of the location variables, `row` and `col`, has not been set yet.

You can use `Integer` instead if you want to check for null:

```
private Integer row = null;
private Integer col = null;

// Has the location been initialized
public boolean isLocationSet()
{
    if(row == null || col == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is due to [the difference between primitive types and reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types) in Java. Java has some built-in types (`int`, `boolean`, `float`, `char`, etc) that can never be `null` and can never be inherited from. It looks like you are trying to compare an `int` (`row`) with `null`. This is an error because an `int` can never be `null`.

You may want to use `Integer` instead, which is a reference type than can be automatically converted to `int`.