# Can anyone help me understand these two programs?

Tags: java

Program 1:

```
public class ValAndRefTypes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x=5;
    addOneTo(x);
    System.out.println(x);

}

static int addOneTo(int num){
    num=num++;
    return(num);//Outputs 5
}
```

Program 2:

```
public class ValAndRefType1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=2,b=3;
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + Add(a,b));
}

 static int Add(int num,int num1){
    num++;
    num1++;
    return(num+num1); //Outputs 7
}
```

Why does the first program not output the incremented value of the variable 'x', but the second program outputs the incremented value of variables 'a' and 'b'?

I also would like to ask whether this has any relation with Value types and Reference types.

TIA for the answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types

Comment: num is a primitive type.  You cannot change it outside the scope of the function.  return as a value instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

**First:**

In the first program, the `addOneTo` function is adding the value and returning the new value (well, attempting to, but we'll get to that below), but that returned value is ignored:

```
addOneTo(x);
```

You don't assign the new value to anything.  Assign it back to the variable:

```
x = addOneTo(x);
```

Whereas in the second program this works because you *are* using the returned value.  You're including it as part of the output:

```
System.out.println("The sum is: " + Add(a,b));
```

---

**Second:**

This line is very misleading, and is confusing the logic being implemented:

```
num=num++;
```

`num++` increments `num`, but *evaluates* to the previous value of `num`.  So the assignment results in assigning back that previous value.  This could work instead:

```
num = ++num;
```

Though that's still clouding the logic for no reason.  Just increment directly:

```
num++;
```

or if you prefer being more explicit:

```
num = num + 1;
```

In the second example, that's how you increment:

```
num++;
num1++;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first program, you are printing "x" which has value 5. Only calling a function does not change the value of "x". If you want to print incremented value the program looks like this:

```
public class ValAndRefTypes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int x=5;
System.out.println(addOneTo(x));
```

}

static int addOneTo(int num){
    num=num++;
    return(num);//It returns 6 not 5
}

Answer (score -1):

Let me make a small change to program 1. You can't mutate a primitive.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x=5;
    int y = addOneTo(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}

static int addOneTo(int num){
    num=num++;
    return(num);
}
```

Comment: I believe the idea was to have the code explained as is, not to change it so it makes more sense.

Comment: This seems kind of misleading.  You certainly *can* assign the result of `addOneTo(x)` back to `x`.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? By just assigning the returned value of the function to another variable the output changes?