# Java printing inherited objects with a println method

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm taking those first steps from python to java and here is my first of many Java questions do doubt.

When printing via a shortened print method, I'm running into a problem with the return value from a inherited class. I'm sure it's something simple about Java I don't get yet. I'm also trying to convert any integers the println method receives to a string with .tostring(), but I'm not sure if that is correct.

```
class Inheritance {

    private static void println (Object line){
        System.out.println(line.toString());
    }

    static class A {
        public int multiply(int a, int b){
            int val = a*b;
            return val;
        }
    }

    static class B extends A {
        public int multiply(int a, int b) {
            int val = a * b * 5;         
            return val;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b_class = new B();
        b_class.multiply(3,4);

        println(b_class);
        println("Hello World");

    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Inheritance$B@74a14482
Hello World
```

Comment: Try `println(b_class.multiply(3,4))`

Comment: This would have worked pretty much the same in Python. You didn't do anything with the `multiply` return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the method inside  `println`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b_class = new B();

        println(Integer.ToString(b_class.multiply(3,4)));
        println("Hello World");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Java** `toString` method default it will

> returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

so when you println `b_class` it will print: `Inheritance$B@74a14482`.

For your `println (Object line)` it's receiving **Reference type(Object)** to println, but as `multiply` method it's **return** a **primitive type(int)**, it's not an object, you need to convert it to an **Object** for `println` method, as @StanteyS's answer, use `Integer.toString` can convert `int` to `String`.

[What's the difference between primitive and reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types)

Answer (score 1):

When you are executing `println(b_class);` implicitly it calls `toString` method of same class, which is inherited from `Object` class.

You need to override `toString` method to display correct output.

```
static class B extends A {
  int val=0;
    public int multiply(int a, int b) {
        val = a * b * 5;         
        return val;
    }
  public String toString(){
   return String.valueOf(val); 
   }
}
```

Now, `println(b_class);` will work as per your expectation.