# What's the Kotlin equivalent of Java's String[]?

Tags: java, kotlin

I see that Kotlin has `ByteArray, ShortArray, IntArray, CharArray, DoubleArray, FloatArray`, which are equivalent to `byte[], short[], int[],char[], double[], float[]` in Java.

Now I'm wondering, is there any `StringArray` equivalent to Java's `String[]`?

Comment: `typealias StringArray = Array<String>` ;)

Answer (score 317, accepted):

There's no special case for `String`, because `String` is an ordinary referential type on JVM, in contrast with [Java primitives (`int`, `double`, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types) -- storing them in a reference [`Array<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) requires [boxing them into objects like `Integer` and `Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). The purpose of specialized arrays like [`IntArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int-array/) in Kotlin is to store non-boxed primitives, getting rid of boxing and unboxing overhead (the same as Java `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`).

You can use `Array<String>` (and `Array<String?>` for nullables), which is equivalent to `String[]` in Java:

```
val stringsOrNulls = arrayOfNulls<String>(10) // returns Array<String?>
val someStrings = Array<String>(5) { "it = $it" }
val otherStrings = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
```

See also: [*Arrays* in the language reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays)

Answer (score 57):

#### Kotlin's array of Strings

To create an empty array of Strings in Kotlin, you should use one of the following six approaches:

---

```
// 01
var empty = arrayOf<String>()
```

---

```
// 02
var empty = arrayOf("","","")
```

---

```
// 03
var empty = Array<String?>(3) { null }
```

---

```
// 04
var empty = arrayOfNulls<String>(3)
```

---

```
// 05
var empty = Array<String>(3) { "it = $it" }
```

---

```
// 06
var empty = Array<String>(0, { _ -> "" })
```

---

However, if you need an array of characters, use the following method:

```kotlin
var charArr = charArrayOf('a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 42):

use  *arrayOf*, *arrayOfNulls*, *emptyArray*

```
var colors_1: Array<String> = arrayOf("green", "red", "blue")
var colors_2: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls(3)
var colors_3: Array<String> = emptyArray()
```

Answer (score 12):

Those types are there so that you can create arrays of the primitives, and not the boxed types. Since String isn't a primitive in Java, you can just use `Array<String>` in Kotlin as the equivalent of a Java `String[]`.

Answer (score 6):

For `Strings` and other types, you just use `Array<*>`.
The reason `IntArray` and others exist is to prevent autoboxing.

So `int[]` relates to `IntArray` where `Integer[]` relates to `Array<Int>`.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the common ways to create a String array are

1. **var arr = Array(5){""}**

This will create an array of 5 strings with initial values to be empty string.

2. **var arr = arrayOfNulls`<String?>`(5)**

This will create an array of size 5 with initial values to be null. You can use String data to modify the array.

3. **var arr = arrayOf("zero", "one", "two", "three")**

When you know the contents of array already then you can initialise the array directly.

4. There is an easy way for creating an **multi dimensional array** of strings as well.

   **var matrix = Array(5){Array(6) {""}}**

   This is how you can create a matrix with 5 rows and 6 columns with initial values of 
   empty string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use too:

```
val frases = arrayOf("texto01","texto02 ","anotherText","and ")
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

This example works perfectly in Android

In kotlin you can use a lambda expression for this. The Kotlin Array Constructor definition is:

```
Array(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
```

Which evaluates to:

```
skillsSummaryDetailLinesArray = Array(linesLen) {
        i: Int -> skillsSummaryDetailLines!!.getString(i)
}
```

Or:

```
skillsSummaryDetailLinesArray = Array<String>(linesLen) {
        i: Int -> skillsSummaryDetailLines!!.getString(i)
}
```

In this example the field definition was:

```
private var skillsSummaryDetailLinesArray: Array<String>? = null
```

Hope this helps