# Kotlin: how to create a 2D Array of the type String

Tags: arrays, 2d, kotlin

i am learning kotlin. i need to create a 2D array which can hold words , special chars and numbers .some where i found this piece of code 
[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICmV7.png)
The problem with this is that it can hold only Int .
When i tried replacing keyword "IntArray" with "string". it returned an error
 [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW20P.png)
Can someone help me create a 10x8 Arrray which can hold strings in Kotlin

Answer (score 11):

There's no `StringArray` in Kotlin [(here's an explanation why)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239869/whats-the-kotlin-equivalent-of-javas-string), use `Array<String>` instead.

If you can provide the array items as you create the arrays, then creating the array can be done as:

```
val result = Array(10) { i ->
    Array(8) { j -> 
        "the String at position $i, $j" // provide some initial value based on i and j
    }
}

println(result[0][3]) // Prints: the String at position 0, 3
```

Otherwise, you can either use some default `String` value:

```
val result = Array(10) { Array(8) { "" } }
```

Or create the inner arrays filled with `null` values (note: you will have to [deal with nullability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), you won't be able to use the items as non-null values):

```
val result = Array(10) { arrayOfNulls<String>(8) } // The type is `Array<Array<String?>>
result[0][0] = "abc"
println(result[0][0]!!.reversed()) // Without `!!`, the value is treated as not-safe-to-use
```

Comment: Good answer, but damn that syntax is ugly. A weak spot of the language IMHO

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **`Array<Array<String>>`**. Note that the compiler can automatically infer this type, but specifying the type may help you understand better what's going on. Here is an example with output:

```
fun main() {
    // Create the 2D array of Strings
    val string2DArray: Array<Array<String>> = arrayOf(
        arrayOf("apple", "orange", "avocado", "mango", "banana"),
        arrayOf("_", "!", ":", "?"),
        arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10"))

    // Print the 2D array
    string2DArray.forEach {
        it.forEach { it -> print("$it, ") }
        println()
    }

    // Access an individual String using index notation.
    println("My favorite fruit is: ${string2DArray[0][2]}")
}
```

**Output**:

```
apple, orange, avocado, mango, banana,
_, !, :, ?,
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10,

My favorite fruit is: avocado
```

Answer (score 0):

When you convert Java codes to Kotlin, sometimes IDE cannot convert it the way it is expected.
Most the of the time I got code as

```
Array(x) { arrayOf(ArrayList<String>(y)) }
```

but this code always throw **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** exception such as

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

So as @hotkey suggested you can use below approach which is also worked for me;

```
Array(x) { Array(y) { ArrayList<String>(y) } }
```