# How to initiate a fixed size array in data class

Tags: kotlin

I tried to research it but didn't find an answer. I'm creating a data class and in that class I would like to create an array with a fixed size. I tried the following 3 options:

```
data class User (
    val profilePics = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
)

data class User (
    val profilePics: Array<String>(3)
)

data class User (
    val profilePics = arrayOfNulls<String>(3)
)
```

But none of them work. 
This does work however:

```
data class User (
    val profilePics: Array<String>
)
```

How can I initialize a fixed-size strings array inside a data class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the Kotlin equivalent of Java's String\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239869/whats-the-kotlin-equivalent-of-javas-string)

Comment: When you are trying to make fixed size array, there is possibility you don't need array at all - just make 3 separate fields.

Comment: Also note that arrays in a data class' primary constructor properties are compared by reference during the equality checks, not by content. For that reason, you may want to use a collection or a custom data structure instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need type annotations on your value parameters.

The following two will compile just fine:

```
data class User (
    val profilePics: Array<String> = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
)

data class User (
    val profilePics: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls<String>(3)
)
```

Of course, nothing prevents the caller from passing in differently sized arrays when creating instances of any of these data classes:

```
val user = User(arrayOf("a", "b", "c", "d")) // compiles fine
```

Comment: Thank you very much Robby it's working and it's interesting to know that you can pass different sizes

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
var list:ArrayList <String> = ArrayList(5)
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid it's working now I upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

try this - hope this help
var array = Array(2){i ->1}

or

var array = arrayOf(1,2,3) // you can increase the size too