# How can you set the default value for array parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I tried below and they don't work

```
fun get (headers: Array<String>= emptyArray())
fun get (headers: Array<String>= null)
fun get (headers: Array<String>= arrayOf(""))
fun get (headers: Array<String>= arrayOfNulls(1))
```

I checked the links below
[What's the Kotlin equivalent of Java's String[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239869/whats-the-kotlin-equivalent-of-javas-string)

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html

Comment: What error message are you getting? `emptyArray()` and `arrayOf("")` should work just fine. `null` works if you declare the argument as nullable (`Array<String>?`), and `arrayOfNulls(1)` works if you declare the *contents* of the array as nullable (`Array<String?>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first line should be fine if you put a space between `>` and `=`.

```
fun get (headers: Array<String> = emptyArray())
```

Comment: I can't believe a space also play such a important role in Kotlin like Python. Google developers really think high of the space.

Comment: @Shui This is one of those rare cases when a space is significant, as `>=` is an operator in itself.

Comment: @Shui Kotlin is developed by JetBrains, not Google.