# Why do push/unshift functions on a list affect other lists that the list is assigned to in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In Javascript, why do the push and unshift functions on a list affect other arrays that the array is assigned to?

For example, if I have an array called *list1* and another array called *list2* and I assign *list1* to *list2* as shown below and I push a value into *list1*, why does *list2* also change?

```js
var list1 = [1,2,3];
var list2 = list1;
list1.push(4);
alert(list2);
// Alerts [1,2,3,4]
```

This is different if I assign an array to *list1*.

```js
var list1 = [1,2,3];
var list2 = list1;
list1 = [1,2,3,4];
alert(list2);
// Alerts [1,2,3]
```

Can somebody please help? This is confusing and makes no sense at all.

Comment: `list1` and `list2` are literally the same array. You've just made two labels for it, rather than copied it in two places.

Comment: Also relevant: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is because Array is not a primitive type. Meaning, if you assign an array to a variable, the variable will be a "pointer" to the Array that is located in the HEAP memory. So if you assign `list2` as `list`, you mean: "Set list2 as the same pointer of list1". In order to make a clone the Array, you can do like so:

```
var list1 = [1,2,3];
var list2 = Array.from(list1);

list1 = [1,2,3,4];
alert(list2);
// Alerts [1,2,3,4];
```

The reason you got [1,2,3] in the second example was that you have assigned list1 to a new List, while list1 still points to the original Array.

You can read more about the difference between primitive and reference tyes here - [What's the difference between primitive and reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types)

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because arrays are reference types in JavaScript. The simple solution to this problem is to clone one list into another instead of assigning.

For example, `list2 = list1.slice(0);`